# Different Aggregation Functions for different tree levels in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have a tree grid with depth of 2. For a column, i needed an aggregation function which is defined by following:

```
        {
            name : 'Name',
            cellClass : cellClass(),
            type : "string",
            treeAggregationType : uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.COUNT,
            customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn : function (aggregation) {
                aggregation.rendered = "good: " + aggregation.value;
            }
        }
```

This is working for its parents of tree level 0 and 1. 
The problem is: I need different aggregation function for different tree levels.

Thus some another function or a check is needed. As far as i know, it is not existing... Every tricky is welcome.